# How to terminate log4cplus in a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, log4cplus

In our project we're using log4cplus indirectly: It is being used in a library that we statically link to, and that project is normally also compiled as a static lib and liked to from our executable. Everything here is Windows and Visual Studio based.

As we've been experiencing problem with application shutdown, I found that we must [initialize log4cplus in our `main()` function](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus#windows-and-visual-studio), which solved the problem.

However, the application we're maintaining is - unfortunately - based on [ACF](http://ilena.org/TechnicalDocs/Acf/Index.html) (*Advanced Component Framework*). That means, the static lib (that links to the static lib that links to log4cplus) can be once more linked with a DLL that is then loaded by an application called *Compositor* during design time. (In Compositor, we can create the target application - which uses the static lib - in a high-level "component-based" fashion...). Now, the problem is that the Compositer would not close properly any more.

When it hangs after closing the main window, we can see the following callstack:

```
    ntdll.dll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId() + 20 bytes Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW() + 265 bytes    Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!SleepConditionVariableSRW() + 45 bytes   Unknown
    msvcp140.dll!__crtSetThreadpoolWait() + 80 bytes    Unknown
    msvcp140.dll!_Cnd_timedwait() + 396 bytes   Unknown
    msvcp140.dll!_Cnd_timedwait() + 84 bytes    Unknown
    log4cplusUx64.dll!log4cplus::helpers::getFileInfo() + 3473 bytes    Unknown
    log4cplusUx64.dll!00007ff86917fefb()    Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!_execute_onexit_table() + 342 bytes    Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!_execute_onexit_table() + 123 bytes    Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!_execute_onexit_table() + 52 bytes Unknown
    log4cplusUx64.dll!log4cplus::helpers::getFormattedTime() + 5056 bytes   Unknown
    log4cplusUx64.dll!log4cplus::helpers::getFormattedTime() + 5364 bytes   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString() + 663 bytes    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownProcess() + 300 bytes  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess() + 173 bytes  Unknown
    kernel32.dll!ExitProcess() + 10 bytes   Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!exit() + 468 bytes Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!exit() + 127 bytes Unknown
>   Compositor.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 295    C++
```

In order to make Compositor close properly, I intorduced a `DllMain` function:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        log4cplus::initialize();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        log4cplus::threadCleanup();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        log4cplus::Logger::shutdown();
        log4cplus::deinitialize();
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Now, the application would no longer start but hang at the call to `log4cplus::initialize()`:

```
    ntdll.dll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId() + 20 bytes Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW() + 265 bytes    Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!SleepConditionVariableSRW() + 45 bytes   Unknown
    msvcp140.dll!__crtSetThreadpoolWait() + 80 bytes    Unknown
    msvcp140.dll!_Cnd_timedwait() + 396 bytes   Unknown
    msvcp140.dll!_Cnd_timedwait() + 84 bytes    Unknown
    log4cplusUx64.dll!00007ff8697360d0()    Unknown
    log4cplusUx64.dll!00007ff86973625f()    Unknown
    log4cplusUx64.dll!log4cplus::spi::FactoryRegistry<log4cplus::spi::LocaleFactory>::FactoryRegistry<log4cplus::spi::LocaleFactory>() + 1438 bytes Unknown
    log4cplusUx64.dll!log4cplus::initialize() + 194 bytes   Unknown
>   MePiaPck.arp!DllMain(HINSTANCE__ * __formal, unsigned long fdwReason, void * __formal) Line 46  C++
```

If I remove that call, startup is normal but the hanging behavior, i.e. Compositer not closing, remains, regardless of `threadCleanup()`, `Logger::shutdown()` and `deinitialize()` (I've tried all combinations).

How can I shutdown log4cplus in a DLL so that the application can terminate properly?

Comment: I can understand the urge to downvote when seeing ACF mentioned...

Comment: who is write `log4cplusUx64.dll` ? here exist some global object which hung in destructor (this is show your first call stack - will be more useful if you use pdb symbols). why you not use `DllMain` from *globalinit.cxx* ? read comments in `thread_callback`. however clear visible that this dll code design only for case when dll loaded at process startup (not via LoadLibrary) and never unloaded. `initialize()` and `deinitialize();` not design to run from loader lock. possible solution create 2 exported functions for init/deinit and call it from exe at begin and end of main.

Comment: Took me a while to decipher your comment.. Thanks, I'll try your final suggestion, although my goal was to _not_ touch the Compositer code - not even sure I'm allowed.

Comment: from fast look for log4cplus src code i understand that `log4cplus::initialize()` not design to execute inside loader lock - it deadlock here. also `deinitialize()` not design too. from your callstack i view you have some global object in `log4cplusUx64.dll` and it destructor deadlock (maybe it called `deinitialize()` - you need use pdb symbols and callstack with it - will be more informative). as solution need have exported functions in dll and call initialize/deinitialize from it and have no global objects in dll which call `deinitialize` in destructor

Comment: @Matz I'm currently evaluating ACF (Advanced Component Framework). There is very little information online. Could you please share some of your experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been mentioned in @RbMm's comments, the reason why initializing log4cplus in `DllMain` does not work is that this function is executed inside the "loader lock" - cf. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices) or [here](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2004/09/why-does-windows-hold-the-loader-lock-whilst-calling-dllmain.html).

The solution is to find a function in the DLL that is executed from the loading application's main thread, and initialize log4cplus there.

In case of [ACF](http://ilena.org/TechnicalDocs/Acf/Index.html)'s *Compositor*, it is the *package export function* that is called first. Normally, it is wrapped as a macro in ACF packages, i.e. `I_EXPORT_PACKAGE`. Unrolling that macro allows for entering the following code:

```
extern "C" I_FUNCTION_EXPORT icomp::CPackageStaticInfo* I_PACKAGE_EXPORT_FUNCTION()
{
    static bool bFirstLoad = true;
    if (bFirstLoad)
    {
        log4cplus::initialize();
        log4cplus::deinitialize();
        bFirstLoad = false;
    }
    return &packageInfo;
}
```

Initializing and deinitializing log4cplus at the first call into the package enables the Compositor application to close and terminate normally again.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question once you found the information! For me the important thing I needed to do was add atexit([](){log4cplus::deinitialize();}) to the main() function so that it is called no matter how the program exits. I also called log4cplus::initialize() as the first line of the main() functon. FYI atexit() is defined in <cstdlib>.